# Adding AlphaBlend property to a panel

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I want to make a panel in my system translucent, like the AlphaBlend property but this property is only available to Tform and not Tpanel. How do I make the panel translucent.

Answer (score 2):

Prior to Windows 8, child controls cannot have the `WS_EX_LAYERED` window style applied to them. That is why non-`TForm` components do not have `AlphaBlend` or `TransparentColor` properties.  What you are asking for it not possible using standard components as-is. Even if you created a custom owner-drawn component, you would still be fighting the system, because you would have to drawn onto the component's `Parent` to achieve the desired effect. You can try looking around for a third-party solution, but you are not likely to find very many options, as using translucent child controls is not a very common practice.

With that said, one simple option you could try is to put the `TPanel` on a separate borderless captionless translucent `TForm`, position the panel `TForm` over the area of the parent `TForm` where you want the `TPanel` to appear (but do not set the panel `TForm`'s `Parent` property or this exercise will not work)  and then move the panel `TForm` in sync with the parent `TForm` whenever it moves around.